# python request error. sys.exit(-(256 - signum))

Tags: python, mysql, request, celery, flask-sqlalchemy

```
            try:
                r = requests.get(url)
            except requests.exceptions.Timeout:
                _LOG.info(f"Loop {i} timeout")
                continue
```

I got error as below,

```
return request(\'get\', url, params=params, **kwargs)\n  
File "/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/requests/api.py", line 61, in request\n    
return session.request(method=method, url=url, **kwargs)\n  
File "/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 542, in request\n    resp = self.send(prep, **send_kwargs)\n  
File "/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 655, in send\n    r = adapter.send(request, **kwargs)\n  
File "/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/requests/adapters.py", line 449, in send\n    timeout=timeout\n  
File "/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 706, in urlopen\n    chunked=chunked,\n  
File "/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 382, in _make_request\n    self._validate_conn(conn)\n  
File "/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 1010, in _validate_conn\n    conn.connect()\n  
File "/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/urllib3/connection.py", line 421, in connect\n    tls_in_tls=tls_in_tls,\n  
File "/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/urllib3/util/ssl_.py", line 450, in ssl_wrap_socket\n    sock, context, tls_in_tls, server_hostname=server_hostname\n  
File "/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/urllib3/util/ssl_.py", line 493, in _ssl_wrap_socket_impl\n    
return ssl_context.wrap_socket(sock, server_hostname=server_hostname)\n  
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/ssl.py", line 401, in wrap_socket\n    _context=self, _session=session)\n  
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/ssl.py", line 808, in __init__\n    self.do_handshake()\n  
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/ssl.py", line 1061, in do_handshake\n    self._sslobj.do_handshake()\n  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/ssl.py", line 683, in do_handshake\n    self._sslobj.do_handshake()\n  
File "/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/billiard/common.py", line 125, in _shutdown_cleanup\n    
sys.exit(-(256 - signum))\n  
File "/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/billiard/pool.py", line 280, in exit\n    
return _exit()\nSystemExit\n'
```

Can anyone let me know what is the issue above, I am using `celery` and `request`, I got ^^ error. I am confused that if this is `celery error` or `request error`. Thanks.

> Also my sqlalchemy got the same issue !

```
File "/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 976, in execute\n    
return self._execute_text(object_, multiparams, params)\n  
File "/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 1151, in _execute_text\n    parameters,\n  
File "/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 1288, in _execute_context\n    e, statement, parameters, cursor, context\n  
File "/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 1485, in _handle_dbapi_exception\n    util.raise_(exc_info[1], with_traceback=exc_info[2])\n  
File "/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sqlalchemy/util/compat.py", line 178, in raise_\n    raise exception\n  
File "/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 1248, in _execute_context\n    cursor, statement, parameters, context\n  
File "/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/default.py", line 588, in do_execute\n    cursor.execute(statement, parameters)\n  
File "/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/MySQLdb/cursors.py", line 247, in execute\n    res = self._query(query)\n  
File "/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/MySQLdb/cursors.py", line 411, in _query\n    rowcount = self._do_query(q)\n  
File "/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/MySQLdb/cursors.py", line 375, in _do_query\n    self._do_get_result()\n  
File "/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/MySQLdb/cursors.py", line 184, in _do_get_result\n    self._result = self._get_result()\n  
File "/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/MySQLdb/cursors.py", line 408, in _get_result\n    return self._get_db().store_result()\n  
File "/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/billiard/common.py", line 125, in _shutdown_cleanup\n    sys.exit(-(256 - signum))\n  
File "/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/billiard/pool.py", line 280, in exit\n    
return _exit()\nSystemExit\n'
```

Answer (score 0):

If you go this issue, please try to update the `celery` version, sometimes it is from your deprecated `celery`.

> I successfully solved this issue after updating to `celery==4.4.2`.

> Also the `message queue` retry sometimes need to be disable from `sql`, it might cause some `wait lock timeout` issue if `celery` unexpected retry.